# Tracking Graduation Progress

Tags: discussion, beta-progress

> **Moderator Note:**
>
> This question has been identified a number of times as being a
>   candidate for migration to Meta.SE - the main meta site.
>
> This question is really about tracking Code Review's 'probable' spot
>   in line, and is not a general purpose all-beta-site tracking system,
>   though it can be used for that.
>
> After discussions with the SE staff as well, it is apparent that this
>   question should stay on this meta site (Code Review).

The following information relates to sites that are in the process of, or recently have, graduated.

- Announcement is when the site was notified that graduation was going to happen.
- DesignMeta ... many times, sites are contacted to say *"Hey, we have started looking at the colors for the site, any ideas?"*
- Colors - when the site actually gets colour ;-)
- Election - when elections nominations start (available on `http://site.se/election`)

Here's the sites so far....

```
Site                      Announcement DesignMeta Colors     Election   Weeks
========================= ============ ========== ========== ========== ========
Money                     2013-03-22   2013-07-24 2014-02-26 2014-03-24      35?
Salesforce                2013-06-11   2014-09-02 2014-09-10 2014-09-22      70?
Graphic Design            2013-08-06   2014-03-04 2014-04-02 2014-04-21       34
Workplace                 2014-02-05   2014-02-05 2014-02-20 2014-03-24       8?
Academia                  2014-03-05   2014-04-11 2014-04-23 2014-05-05      16
Japanese                  2014-03-05   2016-05-24 2016-06-08 2015-11-02
Anime                     2014-03-07?                        2015-08-10
Expression Engine         2014-03-12   2014-11-28 2015-01-14 2015-01-26      45
Movies                    2014-05-21   2015-01-06 2015-01-28 2015-02-17      38?
Chemistry                 2014-09-19   2015-02-02 2015-05-13 2015-07-06      41
Code Review               2014-09-22   2015-11-23 2015-11-25 2015-06-29      61
Music                     2014-09-23   2016-03-07 2016-03-30 2015-11-09
Network Engineering       2015-03-18   2015-04-30 2015-06-23 2015-06-01
Biology                   2015-03-25   2015-05-13 2015-05-20 2015-07-06
Blender                   2015-05-26*  2015-12-03 2016-01-28 2015-06-01
Cryptography              2015-06-06*  2015-12-08 2015-12-21 2015-06-16
Computer Science          2015-07-29   2016-01-20 2016-02-01 2015-08-03
Magento                   2015-08-14   2016-01-26 2016-02-26 2015-08-17
English Language Learners 2015-09-10   2016-02-11 2016-02-25 2015-08-24
Aviation                  2015-11-16   2016-06-20 2016-07-01 2016-03-14
Emacs                     2015-11-16   2016-05-04 2016-05-24 2016-02-08
Signal Processing         2015-11-16   2016-08-16 2016-10-05 2016-03-08
Software Recommendations  2015-11-16   2016-04-18 2016-04-22 2015-11-30
Worldbuilding             2015-11-16   2015-12-17 2016-05-18 2016-02-01
Raspberry Pi              2015-11-17   2015-11-06 2015-11-17 2015-12-07      -2
(PP &) Code Golf          2016-02-23                         2016-03-21
Puzzling                  2016-03-30   2016-03-30 2016-05-04 2016-07-11
Law                       2016-07-06                         2016-07-18
Philosophy                2016-07-06                         2016-07-25
Motor Vehicle M & R       2016-09-13                         2016-10-11
```

Comment: Well, actually, yes. That is one of the reasons this post is important, it is to get a perspective on what happens now, it is not a 'fast' process, so prepare for a marathon, not a sprint.

Comment: [There's feature graduation without colors](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/425/congratulations-youre-about-to-graduate-with-a-twist) now, so maybe you will need another column, soon. Also, there can be quite a gap between a staff member saying, "you are going to graduate (soon)" and the actual announcement (cf [cs.SE]).

Comment: This seems to be the only such overview I can find on the network. Would be great if you guys kept this up-to-date even though you've graduated now. (Congrats!)

Answer (score 6):

## Workplace

- Announcement [Seems that the decision was made long before the announcement](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2333/15986)
- Design Meta [2014-02-05](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2331/15986)
- Colors - [2014-02-20](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/new-design-launched)
- Election - [2014-03-24](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/1/)

Answer (score 6):

## Personal Finance & Money

- Announcement: [2013-03-22](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/713/24536)
- Design Meta: [2013-07-24](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/801/design-for-personal-finance-money)
- Colors: [2014-02-26](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/new-design-launched)
- Election: [2014-03-24](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1941/2014-community-moderator-election)

Answer (score 6):

## Network Engineering

> Special Note: Network engineering is/was identified for a pilot program for rapid promotion, without a design, though, then something changed, and the promotion is now happening *with* a design.

- Announcement: [2015-03-18](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425/congratulations-youre-about-to-graduate-with-a-twist)
- Design Meta: [2015-04-30](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/441/14755)
- Colors: [2015-06-23](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/507/site-graduated-new-design-launched)
- Election: [2015-06-01](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/457/2015-experimental-moderator-election-qa-question-collection)

Answer (score 5):

## Academia

- Announcement: [2014-03-05](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/830) "A few months ago"
- DesignMeta: [2014-04-11](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/891)
- Colors: [2014-04-23](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/906)
- Elections: [2014-05-05](https://academia.stackexchange.com/election/1/)

Answer (score 5):

## Anime & Manga

- Announcement [2014-03-07 (or earlier?)](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/865/6406)
- Design Meta:
- Colors:
- Election:

Answer (score 4):

## Movies & TV

- Announcement: [In a comment on meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1267/900-days-in-beta-where-do-we-stand/1268#comment2788_1268)
- Design Meta: [2015-01-06](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/site-design-for-movies-se)
- Colors: [2015-01-28](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1521)
- Elections: [2015-02-17](https://movies.stackexchange.com/election/1)

Answer (score 4):

## **Graphic Design**

- Announcement: [2013-08-06](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/642)
- Design Meta: [2014-03-04](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/updated-march-14-design-for-graphicdesign-se/839#839)
- Colors: [2014-04-02](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/870/new-design-launched)
- Election: [2014-04-21](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/870/new-design-launched)

Answer (score 4):

## Chemistry:

- Announcement: [2014-09-19](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/484)
- Design Meta: [2015-02-02](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/604/chemistry-site-design-input-welcome)
- Colors: [2015-05-13](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/site-graduated-new-design-launched)
- Election: [2015-06-07](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2778/2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection)

Answer (score 4):

## Expression Engine

- Announcement: [2014-03-12](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/lets-get-critical-mar-2014-site-self-evaluation#comment359_1255)
- Design Meta: [2014-11-28](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1281)
- Colors: [2015-01-14](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1286)
- Election: [2014-01-26](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/2015-community-moderator-election)

Answer (score 4):

## Music: Practice & Theory

- Announcement [2014-09-23](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/925/music-se-is-graduating-congratulations)
- Design Meta:
- Colors:
- Election: [2015-11-09](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2306)

Answer (score 4):

## Biology

- Announcement: [2015-03-25](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2935/when-will-biology-se-become-a-full-se-site) (not sure if this counts)
- Design Meta: [2015-05-13](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/site-design-for-biology-community)
- Colors: [2015-05-20](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/site-graduated)
- Election: [2015-06-07](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection)

Answer (score 3):

## SalesForce

- Announcement: [Announced on the podcast here?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/a/422)
- Design Meta: [based on feedback from SalesForce corp. not from site community](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/740/design-for-salesforce-stack-exchange)
- Colors: [Announced here](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/749)
- Elections: [Completed October 7, 2014](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/election/1/)

Answer (score 3):

## Computer Science

- Declaration of Readiness: [2014-01-07](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/743/when-will-cs-se-graduate#comment2484_747)
- Announcement: [2015-07-29](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/preparing-for-graduation-election-coming-on-august-3-2015)
- Election: [2015-08-03](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/2015-community-moderator-election)
- Graduation: [2015-09-10](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/congratulations-computer-science-is-graduating)
- Design Meta: [2016-01-20](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1189/25735)
- Colors: [2016-02-01](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1211/25735)

Answer (score 2):

### Blender

- Announcement: [2015-05-26](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/moderator-election-coming-soon)
- Design Meta:
- Colors:
- Election: [2015-06-01](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/1)

Answer (score 2):

### Japanese

- Announcement : [2014-03-05](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1155) and [2015-09-10](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1420)
- Design Meta : [Maybe?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/511?m=24113634#24113634)
- Colors :
- Elections : [2015-09-09](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/election/1)

Answer (score 1):

### Software Recommendations

- Announcement: [2015-11-16](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2354)
- Design Meta:
- Colors:
- Election: [2015-11-30](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2354)

Answer (score 1):

### Worldbuilding

- Announcement : [2015-11-16](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2767/congratulations-worldbuilding-is-graduating?cb=1)
- Design Meta : [2015-12-17](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/brainstorming-worldbuilding-site-design)
- Colors : 2016-05-18
- Elections : 2016-02-01

Answer (score 1):

### Aviation

- Announcement: [2015-11-16](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2844)
- Design Meta: [2016-06-20](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2996)
- Colors: [2016-07-01](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3008)
- Election: [2016-03-14](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election)

Answer (score 1):

### Emacs

- Announcement : [2015-11-16](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/341)
- Design Meta :
- Colors :
- Elections :

Answer (score 1):

### Magento

- Announcement : [2015-08-14](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/633)
- Design Meta :
- Colors :
- Elections : [2015-08-28](https://magento.stackexchange.com/election/1)

Answer (score 1):

### Raspberry Pi

- Announcement : [2015-11-17](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/597)
- Design Meta : [2015-11-06](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/589)
- Colors : [2015-11-17](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/597)
- Elections :

Answer (score 1):

### Signal Processing

- Announcement: [2015-11-16](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1332)
- Design Meta:
- Colors:
- Election: